# Issue with ConnectSSL using IMAP4

Tags: imap

I am using IMAP 4 protocol in my c# dotnet windows service, which continuously monitor a configured mail account for downloading mail and then performs a series of business logic. Everything works fine as long as the windows service is installed and configured with in the domain to which the mail exchange is part.

Once the service is installed outside the domain I get certificate issue and I am aware since the mail exchange have a test certificate the below error is logged, I tried to ignore the certificate validation, but this has not worked and also installed the mail exchange test certificate on the machine in which the service is installed but even this failed to work.

**The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ValidateCreateContext(Boolean isServer, String targetHost, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, X509Certificate serverCertificate, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, Boolean remoteCertRequired, Boolean checkCertRevocationStatus, Boolean checkCertName)**

I wanted to know if there are any other protocol(component) apart from IMAP4, which I can use and that allow me to ignore the certificate validation issue.

Any suggestion or help on this would be of great help.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore that certificate validation, instead of importing the certificate into your client's list of roots? Or just getting a proper CA in the first place? Startssl.com will give you a test certificate for free (renewal costs, but who wants to renew a test certificate?)

Comment: Hi arnt, I have already imported the certificate into client list of root, the issue still persist. Getting proper CA is not something I can do. That's the reason I want to ignore certificate validation until we get one.